# pgfplots: Showing tick marks and labels but not axis lines

Tags: pgfplots, tufte

Using `pgfplots`, it's possible to turn on or off printing of axis lines and ticks using `axis lines` for all axes or `axis x line` (*etc.*) for only selected axes. However, sometimes it is desirable to print the ticks and labels but not the axis lines themselves. This is a style not dissimilar to those recommended by [Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/) (see also [Is there a package that provides graphing in the style of Ed Tufte?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29293/is-there-a-package-that-provides-graphing-in-the-style-of-ed-tufte)), but it's useful even if that's not the key concern, for example for making very small plots for abstracts or similar. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Related: There's an article in the upcoming TUGboat about implementing Tufte's "range frames" (axis lines drawn only over the range of the data) and "dash-dot plot" (tick marks used to show the marginal distribution of the data).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of steps required to remove the lines and then 'tidy up' the ticks. The lines are removed using the `axis line style` option

```
axis line style = { draw = none }
```

which unlike setting `axis lines = none` still prints the ticks and labels. However, on its own this prints the tick marks on both the axis with the labels and the one without them: these look a bit strange, so you probably also want to set `tick pos = left` (`pgfplots` uses `left` for both axes!). You may then want to adjust the number of ticks in use: the Tufte style is to have only the tick marks at the edges of the printed range, but that is optional.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
       [
         axis line style = { draw = none },
         xtick           = {-5,5}         ,
         ytick           = {-5,5}         ,
         tick pos        = left           ,
       ]
     \addplot[only marks, color = black] {x};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image]

For very small-scale plots, missing out one of the axes may be sensible: the easies way to do this is to set the ticks to `\empty`, *e.g.* `ytick = \empty`. With no ticks set, the axis then doesn't show up at all.