# Can we draw a distribution via LaTeX code inside a table?

Tags: tables, math-mode, graphics

I would like to draw graphs in a table similar to Table 1 (page 4), "Distribution" column as given in this paper - http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~sbakhshi/gilbert.chi13.pinterest.pdf

Is this an image or can this be drawn using some math LaTeX code?

Comment: Take a look at [Is there a package that provides graphing in the style of Ed Tufte?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29293/is-there-a-package-that-provides-graphing-in-the-style-of-ed-tufte)

Comment: Thanks! The need of the hour was the `sparkline` package. It has minimal documentation but for now it does the job. :)