# tabularx processes its body multiple times; how do I know which cycle I am in?

Tags: conditionals, tabularx

Assume that I enjoy setting my tables using an `\item`ized or list-like coding structure:

```
\begin{mytabular}[.5\textwidth]
  \item head1 & head2% <-- header row
  \item abc & def
  \item ghi & jkl
\end{mytabular}
```

The idea is that I always have the first row being a header row, with subsequent rows representing the items, so the above input should translate to the following output:

```
\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{XX}
  \toprule
  head1 & head 2 \\% <-- header row
  \midrule
  abc & def \\
  ghi & jkl \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

Since each row is identified by an `\item`, appropriate redefinitions of `\item` could be used to tie into discerning whether I'm setting a header/not. Below I've used some delayed redefinition of `\item`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,environ}

\NewEnviron{mytabular}[1][\linewidth]{%
  \let\olditem\item
  \gdef\item{%
    \gdef\item{%
      \\\midrule\gdef\item{%
        \\}}}
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{XX}
    \toprule
    \BODY \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \let\item\olditem
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{mytabular}[.5\textwidth]
  \item head1 & head2
  \item abc & def
  \item ghi & jkl
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

The intent is that the first `\item` should do nothing; the second `\item` should turn into `\\ \midline` and every subsequent `\item` should become `\\`. However, this never happens:

[image]

It turns out `tabularx` processes its body multiple times. Is there a way to establish which cycle of processing I'm in so that one can guarantee appropriate actions to be taken? The aforementioned question is akin to [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s use of `\ifmeasuring@` in an `align`-type display.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

During its trials tabularx makes various local definitions to stop things happening multiple times, or to stop you getting multiple warnings about the bad boxes for bad trials.

In particular it does

```
    \hfuzz=\maxdimen
    \let\hfuzz\@tempdima
```

(Actually without the `=`) so you get no overfull hbox warnings during the trials.

On the final run it does a setting with all these reverted to normal so you can use

```
    \ifx\@tempdima\hfuzz
        trial run
    \else
        final run
    \fi
```

note this needs to be where `@` is a letter or you could use

```
      \expandafter\ifx\csname @tempdima\endcsname\hfuzz
```

Comment: Maybe, for a future release, setting `\hbadness` to some special value above 10000 could be better. Maybe the `tabularx` is in some place where tentative typesetting is done, so the value of `\hbadness` might already be 10000.

Comment: @egreg actually the answer is just as wrong after the edit as it was. My earlier self was too sneaky for my current self. I'll fix

Comment: @egreg try now:-)

Comment: `\@tempdima`? Oh, no!