# Multicolumn within tabularx: how to get p{'lengths'} right

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, lengths

I am trying to have the `lipsum` text fill the two cells to the right of the vertical ruler, without exceeding the `table`.

My code is now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | X X}
\hline
Short \setlength{\mylength}{\hsize} & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum[1]} \\
Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum[2]} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Which yields this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways of getting around the problem.

1. Your usage is correct, but you're not counting the number of `\tabcolsep`s correctly. There are 6 within your table stemming from the `tabularx` preamble `{l | X X}`. Let's denote a `\tabcolsep` using `t`, then you'd have `{tlt|tXttXt}`. Moreover, the calculation of `\hsize` is for the entire "`tlt`-column", so it already includes 2 `\tabcolsep`s. So, what you need in your calculation is to remove 8 `\tabcolsep`s:

   ```
   \noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | X X}
     \hline
     Short\setlength{\mylength}{\hsize} & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
     & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[1]} \\
     Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
     & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[2]} \\
   \end{tabularx}
   ```

   I've dropped the use of the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc), hence the visible `\dimexpr`. Also note that I've removed the space between `Short` and `\setlength`, as this actually influences the size of `\hsize`.
2. Capture the column content, store it in a box and measure it all during [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)'s [measuring phase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227142/5764) (...not all that necessary, but still):

   ```
   \newcommand{\capturemaxwidth}[1]{%
     % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227142/5764
     \ifdim\hfuzz=\maxdimen\relax% trial run
       \setbox9=\hbox{#1}% Store content in box
       \ifdim\mylength>\wd9\relax% Measure box width...
         \setlength{\mylength}{\wd9}% ...and possibly store width
       \fi
     \fi  
     #1% final run
   }

   ...

   \noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L | X X}
     \hline
     Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
     & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[1]} \\
     Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
     & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[2]}
   \end{tabularx}
   ```

The second option removes some of the construction from your code, placing it in the preamble. As such, the code might be slightly better to read. Your choice. Both have an output resembling:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\capturemaxwidth}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\newlength{\mylength}
\newcommand{\capturemaxwidth}[1]{%
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227142/5764
  \ifdim\hfuzz=\maxdimen
    \setbox9=\hbox{#1}% trial run
    \ifdim\mylength>\wd9
      \setlength{\mylength}{\wd9}%
    \fi
  \fi  
  #1% final run
}
\begin{document}

\sloppypar% Just for this example, due to lipsum

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | X X}
  \hline
  Short\setlength{\mylength}{\hsize} & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[1]} \\
  Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[2]} \\
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L | X X}
  \hline
  Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[1]} \\
  Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-\mylength}}{\lipsum*[2]}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If doing that calculation by hand, you have pre-calculated the X width so you could save tex a lot of work and use tabular an p columns rather than tabularx

Answer (score 4):

Set `\mylength` to the width of `Short` (or whaterver you use)

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{Short}
```

and then

```
p{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth-\mylength\relax}
```

should do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{Short}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | X X}
\hline
Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth-\mylength\relax}}{\lipsum[1]} \\
Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth-\mylength\relax}}{\lipsum[2]} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `tabularx` (According to David, to save some memory) you can do this (Since we do manual calculations anyway):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{Short}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l | *{2}{p{(\dimexpr\textwidth-\mylength-6\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax)/2}}}
\hline
Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} &  And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth-\mylength\relax}}{\lipsum[1]} \\
Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth-\mylength\relax}}{\lipsum[2]} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You cam get rid of those 2 `bad boxes` by using `\raggeright` in

```
\begin{tabular}{l | *{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\dimexpr\textwidth-\mylength-6\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax)/2}}}
\hline
```

Comment: If doing that calculation by hand, you have pre-calculated the X width so you could save tex a lot of work and use tabular an p columns rather than tabularx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right.  I will make some addition.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `X` which gives you the basic unit width for an expanding column, but you need to double it and allow for the `2\tabcolsep` in the middle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | X X}
\hline
Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}}X}{\lipsum[1]} \\
Short & \textbf{This text is a little bit longer} & And here is some more and more \\
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}}X}{\lipsum[2]} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```