# Alias normalbaselineskip to \\ in a tabularx environment

Tags: tables, macros, environments, tabularx

I'm [still on my way to my key:value table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227111/66964), and this time, I'm trying to alias `[\normalbaselineskip]` to `\\`. I still want to use the standard `\\`. What I want is to consider `\\` as `[\normalbaselineskip]` only if it follows directly (without space) another `\\`. Typically, if I type `\\\\` in the tabularx environment below, the first needs to be interpreted as a standard `\\` and the second as `[\normalbaselineskip]`. Where things goes tricky is that I want, if possible, to restrict the scope of that `\\\\` alias only to this tabularx (keyvalue) environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\newenvironment{keyvalue}
{\tabularx{\textwidth}{X@{ : }X}}
{\endtabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{keyvalue}
    Foo bar lorem ipsum           & Lorem ipusm que \\
    Some number                   & 12 3456 789  8  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{This is some comment}        \\[\normalbaselineskip]
    Yet some number               & 987 65432 1     \\
    Foo bar                       & 163883495778    \\[\normalbaselineskip]
    Bar lorem ipsum               & 2013-04-12      \\
\end{keyvalue}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The main intent here is to avoid the printing of `:`, correct?

Comment: Sounds confusing to me.  Why not just use a macro? That's what they're for, after all.  Something like `\newcommand{\wget}{\\[\normalbaselineskip]}`....

Comment: `\newcommand{\wgetbreak}{\addlinespace[\normalbaselineskip]}` and add `\wgetbreak` after ``\\`` where you want more space.

Comment: @Werner This isn't the subject of this question, but yes, one of the intend of `  \multicolumn{2}{l}{This is some comment}` is to avoid the colon `:` to be printed when there is only one element in the row.

Comment: @jon @egreg Creating an alias/macro is the purpose of this question ;-)
If you read correctly, I don't want to have a new command like `\wget` or `\wgetbreak` which I could have defined by myself, but `\\` instead which doesn't conflict with the existing `\\` meaning.

Comment: I understand the 'want', but I don't get the 'why'? For fun? Or will it actually do anything that a macro cannot?

Comment: @jon: the 'why' is just because it is more convenient for the user who will use my class file. I tried with \renewcommand{\\\\}{\\[\normalbaselineskip]}
but I've got unexpected errors:
Undefined control sequence. \renewcommand{\\\\}
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \renewcommand{\\\\}
I even tried with \let to avoid loops. But no result.

Comment: a command may consist only of one escape character (ordinarily ``\\``) and either (a) any number of letters, or (b) only one non-letter.  since you can't redefine `\ ` to be a letter, trying to redefine ``\\\\ `` is simply impossible.

Comment: Aside from the impossibility, you might consider whether it is a good coding practice. Tastes differ, of course, but (to me) what you would gain in 'convenience' does not compensate for the lost readability of the input file. If a user thinks she can write `\\ ` or `\\\\ `, then might she not then want `\\\\\\ `? (or, why not: `\\\\\ `?) Macros can have relatvely intuitive and meaningful names like `booktabs`' `\addlinespace` -- which is also useful when you revisit a file several years later because `\addlinespace` has a pretty unambiguous meaning that your collection of slashes mostly lacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, defining a new command as `\\\\` is impossible, because redefining `\` conflicts with the existing meaning of `\` used as an escape sequence.

Even if `\\\\` seems to be more convenient to type instead of `\\[\normalbaselineskip]`, this is not a good coding practise (loss of readability). Use cases like adding more backslashes should have been handled with care too, increasing the risk to have an infinite loop, like I experienced.

A compromise I made was to use a macro, like proposed, but a shorter one: `\x`.

Here is the new definition of the `keyvalue` environnement I have:

```
\newenvironment{keyvalue}
{%
    \newcommand{\x}{\\[\normalbaselineskip]}%
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X@{ : }X}%
}
{\end{longtabu}}
```

Yes, in the meantime, I migrated from `tabularx` to `tabu` allowing long tables (like the package `longtable`, but with way more features to it).