# Why \\[2\baselineskip] has no effect inside tabular

Tags: tables, line-spacing

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\sample{text text text text text}
\def\Sample{\sample\sample}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\Sample\\
\Sample\\[2\baselineskip]
\Sample

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c}
\Sample\\
\Sample\\[2\baselineskip]
\Sample
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produce

[image]

As you can see `\\[2\baselineskip]` add vertical space of `2\baselineskip` after line break outside `tabular` environment.

If we add `\\[2\baselineskip]` inside `tabular` there is no effect as though the length `\baselineskip` became 0pt, why is this happening and how to fix it ( add vertical space of `2\baselineskip` inside tabular), thanks.

Comment: You could use  `\addlinespace` from the  `booktabs` package. Or use a new tabular line and add a rule of zero width but fixed height: `\rule{0pt}1cm}`

Comment: `\baselineskip` is 0pt inside tables. You can use `\normalbaselineskip`.

Comment: it is not "as though `\baselineskip` became 0pt"  : `\baselineskip` _is_ 0pt.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227111/baselineskip-not-interpreted-in-a-tabularx-keyvalue-environment/227121#227121

Comment: Use [2ex] Instead